# COBOL Confusion

Tags: cobol

Hey, everyone.  I'm having a bit of trouble in a coding project that I'm trying to tackle in the zOS environment using COBOL.  I need to read a file in and put them into an indexed  table (I know there will be less than 90 records).

The thing that is throwing me is that we are bound by the parameters of the project to use a variable called "Table-Size" (set to zero at declaration).

Given all that, I need to do something like "Occurs 1 to 90 times Depending on Table-Size", but I don't understand how that will work if table-size has to (as far as I can tell) because table-size is incremented along with each entry that is added to the table.  Can anyone please clear this up for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like your primary concern is: how does the compiler know how much to allocate in the array if the size changes at run-time?

The answer is that it allocates the *maximum* amount of space (enough for 90 entries). Note that this is for space in *working storage*. When the record is written to a *file*, only the relevant portion is written.

An example:

```
01  TABLE-SIZE  PIC 9
01  TABLE OCCURS 1 TO 9 TIMES DEPENDING ON TABLE-SIZE
    03 FLD1  PIC X(4)
```

This will allocate 36 characters (9 multiplied by 4) for `TABLE` in working storage. If `TABLE-SIZE` is set to 2 when the record is written to a *file,* only 8 characters of `TABLE` will be written (over and above the characters written for `TABLE-SIZE`, of course).

So, for example, if the memory occupied by `TABLE` was `AaaaBbbbCcccDdddEeeeFfffGgggHhhhIiii`, the date written to the file may be the shortened (including size): `2AaaaBbbb`.

Similarly, when the record is read back in, both `TABLE-SIZE` and the relevant bits of `TABLE` will be populated from the file (setting only the size and first two elements).

I don't believe that the unused `TABLE` entries are initialised to *anything* when that occurs. It's best to assume not anyway, and populate them explicitly if you need to add another item to the table.

For efficiency, you may want to consider setting the `TABLE-SIZE` to `USAGE IS COMP`.

Comment: This was precisely what I was trying to understand.  Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: The processing of variable-length data is alread lengthy. Using a USAGE DISPLAY field for the ODO variable adds to that, for no purpose. Define that as "binary".

Comment: @Bill, that's a good point though related tangentially to the question in my opinion. I'll add a note since it's definitely good advice.

Comment: The question is "how to use OCCURS DEPENDING ON". The compiler deals with ODO in binary, so a binary definition of the ODO field seems a non-tangential suggestion. USAGE DISPLAY or COMP-3/PACKED-DECIMAL will work, but will always involve extra generated code if a higher-level group item is referenced, like writing it to a file. I have no clue about what you mean by "to and from binary" becoming more complex beyond nine.

Comment: @Bill, I would say the question was more to do with how the size variable controls the array. The way the size variable controls the usage doesn't change depending on whether the size is binary or display though, as agreed, binary is more efficient since there's no conversion needed. As to the "9" boundary, that was just for the resulting machine code. If it's 9 or less, it's a simple AND operation with 0x0f to turn an EBCDIC numeric character (0xf0 thru 0xf9) into binary. At greater than 9, you need both that _and_ some `x * 10 + y` type calculations to turn display vars into binary.

Comment: Mmmm... you must be using a different compiler. Which are you using? Not one known to me, which has always been PACK/CVB.

Comment: Actually, the compiler we're using is an internal one. For simpler cases, it can sometimes just use AND rather than the more elaborate CVB. I have no idea whether the compilers IBM release to the wild have similar capabilities. But, since that may _not_ be the case, I'll remove the comment.

Comment: I'm getting tidier with more experience. Shall we delete all these comments now?

Answer (score 2):

We don't have quite enough information here, but the basic thing is that the variable named in the DEPENDING ON clause has to have a count of the variable number of groups.  So you need something like

```
01   TABLE-SIZE     PIC 99
01   TABLE OCCURS 1 TO 90 TIMES
       DEPENDING ON TABLE-SIZE
    03 FIELD-1
    03 FIELD-2
```

and so on.

See [this article](http://www.3480-3590-data-conversion.com/article-cobol-occurs.html) or [this article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.cbl.win.doc/topics/tptbl27.htm) at Publib.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference material, Charlie.  I shall review it, and I am certain that it will help me in the future

Thanks!

Comment: Same as above. Make TABLE-SIZE "binary".